# Celestia compilation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, compilation

So after years of using other distros, I decided to go back to ubuntu, and was surprised that celestia was no longer in the repositories, so I decided to compile it from source. It was a nightmare trying to install all the missing dependencies, but I managed to get to make. Here's the error I got...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUcN5.png)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here, questions and answers are designed to be easy-searchable, so please add the error message as text. Also helpful: Adding the commands which are necessary to get the dependencies (apt-get or wget) and build

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: I would gladly add the error message as text, however the code toolbar does not give me an option to indent everything as required for the edit.